# Is a Lebesgue integrable function on a compact set bounded?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, compactness

Suppose that $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function and it is Lebesgue integrable on a compact set $C$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$.  Then my question is, does $f$ have to be bounded on $C$?

This is a true property of continuous functions, but of course a Lebesgue integrable function need not be continuous.

Comment: No.  Just make the function value $\infty$ at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, of course: consider $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^{-1/2}&\text{if }x\in(0,1]\\0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: But is it Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes; specifically, $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=2$.